# localhost: Подключение не защищено

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, https, iis, localhost

Подключаю asp.net веб-приложение к базе, лежащей у меня на компьютере, перехожу по адресу localhost/web - всё заходит как надо.

Подключаю приложение к базе не лежащей у меня локально (размещенной скорее всего где-то в Германии) - переадресовывает на https://.... и выдаёт следующее сообщение.

Как можно это исправить? На другую (нелокальную) базу подключается хорошо. Ошибка только при подключении к этой БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это говорит что на данном сервисе(https) не зарегестрирован  SSL сертификат, SSL сертификаты выдаются центрами сертификации, используйте http и не будет проблем с сертификатом(если хотите)

Comment: так я использую http, оно автоматом перебрасывает на https

Comment: поменять https на http(как поменять в вашем случае я не знаю) или купить сертификат от 20$ в год

Comment: может там где лежит ваша база( где-то в Германии) нету сертификата, но они работают с  https